# AWS Cloudwatch agent not forwarding some windows event logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

So, I have setup CWA to follow windows events logs in following way:

```
"windows_events": {
            "collect_list": [
                {
                    "event_format": "xml",
                    "event_levels": [
                        "INFORMATION",
                        "WARNING",
                        "ERROR",
                        "CRITICAL"
                    ],
                    "event_name": "Application",
                    "log_group_name": "XXXXXXX",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}",
                    "retention_in_days": 30
                }
            ]
        }
```

When I check this log-group on AWS console, for some reason there are only events from provider: "Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP", but nothing from providers ".NET Runtime" or "VstsAgentService" although I can see both of them on Event viewer on the Application channel. Same event levels.

I am puzzled, why it seems to work with some events and not with others.

Comment: Even I have the same issue. When I add, both System & Application events, first time, I saw both. But after I made some changes in config, from 2nd time onwards, I couldn't see the Application events. Even the custom file is not being logged

Comment: Has any progress been made on this. Not seeing app pool recycle events, .net events or general IIS start stop events.